# Метод extend() в Python

Tags: python, методы, теория, extend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно.
В книге Васильева столкнулась с формулировкой "Метод extend() позволяет добавить в конец списка, из которого вызывается метод, элементы списка, указанного аргументом метода extend()." На просторах интернета встречались подобного характера утверждения. Проверила строковый литерал в качестве аргумента метода - метод работает и со строковым литералом. Подскажите, получается в метод extend()
в качестве аргумента можно передавать любой итерируемый объект, верно? Не только список?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну да, в документации так и написано https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ. ПОЧИТАЛА ДОКУМЕНТАЦИЮ.)))